# Java detect special characters in a string

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I use regex

```
r="[^A-Za-z0-9]+";
```

to detect if a string has one or more chars other than letters and digits;

Then I tried the following:

```
Pattern.compile(r).matcher(p).find();
```

I tested:

```
! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) +  =- [ ] \ ' ; , . / { } | " : < > ? ~ _ `
```

Most of the time, it works except backsplash \ and caret ^.

e.g.

```
String p = "abcAsd10^"    (return false)
String p = "abcAsd10\\"   (return false)
```

Anything I miss?

Comment: I get matches for "abcAsd10\\" and "abcAsd10^", so here it returns true. Note that I use C# so I think it has to to with Java. It can help if you write a little code sample that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: FWIW, both strings appear to match [on Ideone](http://ideone.com/KmWPk).

Comment: Sorry, I had r="[^A-za-z0-9]+"; (with little "z"). That causes returning "false"

Comment: So you  have your answers now? Not clear if you had a type in your so question or the problem itself.

Comment: I had r="[^A-za-z0-9]+"; in my code (with little "z", i.e. A-z). That causes returning "false". But why it works with other special chars except backsplash \ and caret ^?

Answer (score 2):

The following code prints "Found: true" when I compile and run it:

```
class T
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String thePattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]+"; 
        String theInput = "abskKel35^";
        boolean isFound = Pattern.compile(thePattern).matcher(theInput).find();
        System.out.println("Found: " + isFound);
    }
}
```

Not sure why you would see a different result...

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
r="[^A-Za-z0-9]+";
```

In your question you write a_z (underscore)

Answer (score 1):

You could also change only:

```
[\w&&^_]+
```

Where:

- `\w` A word character with underscore: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`
- `\W` A non-word character: `[^\w]`

See more in class [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Perhaps it might be interesting to experience another way.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code on my machine it prints true..

```
        String r="[^A-Za-z0-9]+"; 
        String p = "abcAsd10\\" ;
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(r).matcher(p);
        System.out.println(m.find());
```

> true

Comment: Originally he had `[^A-Za_z0-9]+`

Comment: so we need to flag this question... it is nothing but a bug

Comment: The original one ([^A-Za_z0-9]+) should give true, Paul. Aynone try '[^A-za_z0-9]+'?

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting your input into the matcher.

```
Pattern.quote(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had

```
r="[^A-za-z0-9]+"; (with little "z", i.e. A-z).
```

That causes returning "false". But why it works with other special chars except backsplash \ and caret ^?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
p.matches(".*\\W.*"); //return true if contains one or more special character
```